# Tinymce and j is null using tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, "textarea_id");

Tags: jquery, class, tinymce, selection

I am using `TinyMCE` on my website, and keep running into the error:

```
j is null
```

I am loading a file via ajax, which contains a `textarea`. I then perform:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'id');
```

Before I call `TinyMCE` again, I use:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'id');
```

However, this results in the `j is null` error.

I have broken down `tinymce.js` into lines, and `j` is within the class selection. More specifically, inside the `getRng` function, as documented here:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#class_tinymce.dom.Selection.html

My guess is that there is still something in the browser memory stack after the control is removed? Either way, I could really use a solution to the problem.

Comment: i recommend using the not minified tinymce-js code (tinymce_dev.js). this way it is far easier to track down problems.

Comment: I managed to get it working puting the 2 commands 'mceAddControl' and 'mceRemoveControl' inside functions. They are now separated from the file I call by ajax. For whatever reason if I put this 2 commands together in the file I call using ajax they got mess up. I thought was timing issue but I guess it is not. I used the same library for a simple testing and it works ok but is doind weird things when I go back to the code I use for the website.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can't separate the js from the ajax :(

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of TinyMCE?  I had this issue in Internet Explorer only but an update and use of `tinymce.remove("id")` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs sporadically, perhaps you are not listening to TinyMCE events like oninit, etc. to ensure that it's ready when you are performing actions on it.